# java synchronized on object vs synchronized on this

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronize

i want to write own simple semaphore and done it as follows:

```
class Semaphore {
    private boolean done;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public Semaphore(boolean done){ this.done = done;}

    public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (!done)
                lock.wait();

            done = false;
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            done = true;
            lock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine. But if i replace synchronized (lock) with synchronize (this) it begins to throw IllegalMonitorStateException. Why so?

Comment: lock.wait() should be changed to this.wait() also. So lock.notify().

Comment: @Alexei yep, but my question is "why this exception is being thrown", not "how to do it works"

Answer (score 2):

As @Alexei Kaigorodov mentioned in comment, when you replace `synchronized (lock)` with `synchronize (this)`. Then, you need to also replace `lock` to `this` in your code.

As `this` indicate to current object which is different than `lock` object.

Now, you replaced `synchronized (lock)` with `synchronize (this)` which means now you are trying to acquire lock on current object but you were waiting on object of Object class.

This works absolutely fine :

```
public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this) {
        while (!done)
            this.wait();

        done = false;
    }
}

public void release() {
    synchronized (this) {
        done = true;
        this.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: u said: "As this indicate to current object which is different than lock object." Yes, but `this` object contains `lock` object so i suppose that synchronizing on `this` object should block all operations on all members of my class. Isn't it?

Comment: i mean that synchronized on `this` should work as synchronized on all members of the class, since `this` represents entire object and includes all members

Comment: To answer you first question. No, they aren't same.

Comment: @borune synchronizing on anything does not block any operation, except another synchronizing  from another thread. All other blockings are merely agreements, which can or cannot be fulfilled in the program.